# I have a list though I keep getting ":argument of type 'str' is not iterable"

Tags: python, ironpython

I am breaking my head about this as this is an error that looks should not be there.

The error I keep getting is:

```
Exception: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.TypeErrorException: argument of type 'str' is not iterable
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
```

The code section is:

```
newAssetDataRows = filter(lambda row: row.GetColumnByName('Original number').Value != '' and row.GetColumnByName('Item Id').Value != '' and row.GetColumnByName('Parent Id').Value == '', assetDataContainer.Rows)
Log.Write("newAssetDataRows length: " + str(len(newAssetDataRows)))
for row in newAssetDataRows:
```

when it gets to for command the script breaks.

The log function writes "newAssetDataRows length: 0" to our log.

Comment: Sounds like nothing is getting entered into newAssetDataRows...

Comment: if `newAssetDataRows` length is `0` what do you expect to iterate through

Comment: yeah, but should the script break and also with the message I am getting?

Comment: funny exception you are getting there, because `str` is actualy [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable)

Comment: Apparently IronPython may report the wrong type in that error: http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/35126

Comment: then the error would happen on the first line, since filter will return an `iterable`. So it seems like `assetDataContainer.Rows` is not an iterable, however in that case - how does the execution continue when an exception has been raised?

Comment: Hi @Rusty. assetDataContainer.Rows is a list and the script continues execution after it coupled with the log command. Where it breaks is the for loop, I have tested it. I am still not sure how to resolve is, as it is obvious newAssetDataRows  is a list

Comment: @interjay, thanks for the reply. But what I have is surely a list, that is what filter should return by definition. So, no exception should be raized here.

Comment: @Срба if `newAssetDataRows` is a `list` then it could not possibly break here. So either it brakes inside the `for` loop or `newAssetDataRows` is not a `list` or even maybe there's a bug in the interpreter (which is probably not the case).

Comment: @Rusty, if I add an additional log print line after the one above: Log.Write("is newAssetDataRows list : " + str(type(newAssetDataRows) is list)) what I get in the log is "is newAssetDataRows list : True". So, it is the list. Then it appears to be a bug in the interpreter?

Comment: @Срба That's all I got man, I have no idea what else could it be anymore. So I guess it's a possibility of interpreter bug, but I doubt it. Try to simplify your code until the bug disappears, maybe then you will see why... Please notify if you have found the solution, I am really puzzled.

Comment: if you try 2.7.5b3 you will get the correct type of the offending "not iterable". I would also explode the whole thing into `for` loop with couple of ifs, to get a better feeling where the problems comes from.